# pushing api responses to global variable inside .map() somehow makes data inaccessible

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I created a function that makes a series of API calls through a Promise like this

```
//userApiList is a variable with an array of links
return Promise.all(userApiList.map(url =>{
    var a = $.getJSON(url);
    //userData is a global variable
    userData.push(a);
    return a;
}));
```

I want to both save the data to a variable for later use and return it right away to be iterated into html with jquery.  Everything loads up perfectly as expected, however when I go to access the data in the variable I get all "undefined" properties.  I console.logged the variable and it shows the data is there, I click the buttons well after the data is fetched so it's not an async issue.   here's an example of one of the functions

```
$("#load_online").click(function(){
    var users = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < userData.length; i++){
      var status = userData[i].status;
      if(status !== null || status !== undefined){ users.push(userData[i]); }
    }
    $("#result_frame").empty();
    //loadUsers() iterates the data into html
    loadUsers(users);
});
```

I tried `console.log(userData[i].status)` just to see what the results would be and I got `200` as a response when it's suppose to be `null'` or the title of an episode being streamed on the channel.

The problem is I thought the `responseJSON:` field is what's always returned for use, as I've never walked into this issue before.  This time it seems the whole object is being read therefore `userData[i].status` was reading the `status:` property a layer up rather than inside the `responseJSON:` object.  I tried thinkering with getting a response out of `userData[i].responseJSON.status` and that returned undefined for each object.  Does anybody readily see what I'm doing wrong?  here's a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Optiq/pen/RygmYy?editors=1010) of the overall project if you need a closer look at things.

Comment: You should have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Comment: From your commentts, you're having trouble applying the answers to your code. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)). (Obviously you'll have to emulate the ajax part, probably with `setTimeout`.) That way we can see what you're doing and help you fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not pushing the *data* into your array, you're pushing a jQuery jqXHR object (which is *thenable*, e.g., Promise-like) into it (that's what the return value of `$.getJSON` is). The reason the `Promise.all` result works is that `Promise.all` waits for those thenables to resolve.

It's quite likely you don't want to have a `userData` global at all. Instead, have whatever code needs the data get it from a resolution handler on the the promise returned by `Promise.all`.

But if you really want to populate `userData`, wait for resolution:

```
return Promise.all(userApiList.map($.getJSON))
    .then(results => {
        userData.push(...results);
        return results;
    });
```

Note that `userData` won't have the data until the ajax requests complete (of course).

The above won't add the results to `userData` until they're **all** avaialble. You also have the option of populating it as you go:

```
return Promise.all(userApiList.map(url => $.getJSON(url).then(result => {
        userData.push(result);
        return result;
    })));
```

But it's important to remember the results will be added over time, not instantaneously, as the requests complete.

If you wait for all of them, `Promise.all` will ensure they're in the same order as the promises you giave it; if you add them as you go, they may not be in that order (because you're pushing as each one completes, and an earlier one may complete after a later one).

Comment: I'm a little confused as to the difference you'r pointing out.  The first one doesn't have the `url` to pass into the `$getJSON`.  The 2nd one recreates the same issue except nothing on the screen changes

Comment: @Optiq: *"I'm a little confused as to the difference you'r pointing out."* As I said above: The first one populates `userData` all at once when the whole process finishes, the second populates it as each call individually finishes. *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* *"The first one doesn't have the url to pass into the $getJSON"* Yes, it does. Note I'm passing `$.getJSON` itself, directly, into `then`. It will get called by the promise resolution, passing it `url`. `.then($.getJSON)` is effectively the same as `.then(url => $.getJSON(url))` (other than what `this` is during the `getJSON` call, but `getJSON` doesn't care about `this`). *"The 2nd one recreates the same issue except nothing on the screen changes"* Then you're trying to use `userData` before it's fully populated.

Answer (score 0):

agreed with the upper answer,

this may work too,

`return userApiList.map(url => { $.getJSON(url).done(function(results){
  userData.push(results)
});})`